# Anaconda and pip

Tags: python, pip, conda

Configuring a [conda environment.yaml](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file), I can set certain packages to be installed by pip. Are these installations also localized to that conda environment somehow, or is that guarantee only given to packages installed directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, packages installed with pip in a conda environment are also localized to that environment. This is because the pip installation process is isolated from the global Python environment. When you install a package with pip, it is installed in the site-packages directory of the conda environment. This directory is not shared with the global Python environment.

To see this for yourself, you can create a conda environment and then install a package with pip. For example, the following command will create a conda environment named myenv and then install the numpy package with pip:

1. conda create -n myenv
2. conda activate myenv
3. pip install numpy

Now, if you list the contents of the site-packages directory, you will see that the numpy package is installed there:

.ls site-packages/
.numpy

If you create a new conda environment, the numpy package will not be installed in that environment by default. You will need to install it again with pip.

This isolation of pip installations is one of the benefits of using conda environments. It allows you to create different environments with different dependencies, without affecting the global Python environment. This can be helpful for managing dependencies for different projects or for avoiding conflicts between packages.

Comment: Your commands are wrong. This way, you would install to a python outside of the created conda env, because there is neither python nor pip in the created environment. You need to do `conda create -n myenv python pip` to have python and pip in the newly created env